# Prove that $\sum\limits_{n=1}(-1)^n\frac{x^2+n}{n^2}$ uniformly convergent on $[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

I used the cauchy criteria, for $p>q$

$$\sup\limits_{x\in [a,b]}\left | S_p(x) -S_q(x)\right |=
\sup\limits_{x}\left | \sum\limits_{k=q+1}^{p}(-1)^n\frac{x^2+n}{n^2} \right |\leq \\ 
\sup\limits_{x}\sum\limits_{k=q+1}^{p}\left | \frac{x^2+n}{n^2} \right |\leq 
\sup\limits_{x}\frac{x^2+q+1}{(q+1)^2}(p-q)=\\
\frac{b^2+q+1}{(q+1)^2}(p-q)$$

Is what I am doing right till now ?

Comment: If you were correct with this reasoning then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^2+n}{n^2}$ must converge to get the Cauchy argument to work on the RHS.  Do you think it does converge? Note $\frac{x^2+n}{n^2} \geqslant \frac{n}{n^2} = \frac{1}{n}$. The simple comparison test shows it diverges like the harmonic series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the series is not absolutely convergent, using the bound,

$$\left|\sum_{n=p+1}^q (-1)^n\frac{x^2+n}{n^2}\right| \leqslant \sum_{n=p+1}^q\frac{x^2+n}{n^2},$$

you will not succeed in proving that partial sums of $\sum_{n \geqslant 1}(-1)^n\frac{x^2+n}{n^2}$ satisfy the Cauchy criterion uniformly because the RHS is the difference of partial sums for a divergent series. Note that $\frac{x^2+n}{n^2} = \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n} \right)$.

For the bounding series to satisfy the Cauchy criterion, we must have for any $\epsilon > 0$,

$$\sup_{x \in [a,b]}\sum_{n=q+1}^{p} \frac{x^2+n}{n^2} < \epsilon $$

for **all** sufficiently large $q$ and $p > q$.

However,

$$\sup_{x \in [a,b]}\sum_{n=q+1}^{p} \frac{x^2+n}{n^2} \geqslant \sup_{x \in [a,b]}(p-q) \frac{x^2 +q }{p^2} = (p-q) \frac{\max(a^2,b^2) +q }{p^2} $$

Taking $p = 2q$, we have

$$\sup_{x \in [a,b]}\sum_{n=q+1}^{p} \frac{x^2+n}{n^2} \geqslant q \frac{\max(a^2,b^2) +q }{4q^2} = \frac{1 + \max(a^2,b^2)/q}{4},$$

and since the RHS converges to $1/4$ as $q \to \infty$, the Cauchy criterion is violated.

**A correct approach**

Uniform convergence can be established using [Dirichlet's test](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_Test_for_Uniform_Convergence). The hypotheses are met since the partial sums $\sum_{n=1}^N(-1)^n$are uniformly bounded and it can be shown that as $n \to \infty$, we have

$$\frac{x^2 + n}{n^2 } \downarrow 0,$$

where the convergence is monotonic and uniform for $x \in [a,b]$.

The uniform convergence is easily established since,

$$\frac{\min(a^2,b^2)+n}{n^2} \leqslant \frac{x^2+n}{n} \leqslant \frac{\max(a^2,b^2) +n}{n^2}$$

See if you can finish by showing that $\frac{x^2 + n}{n^2}$ is decreasing with respect to $n$.

Summation by parts is another approach, but that in essence repeats the steps in a  proof of Dirichlet's test for uniform convergence.

Answer (score 0):

Good way! Now each time let $p=\lfloor\alpha q\rfloor$ with some $\alpha>1$
therefore$$\sup_{x\in [a,b]}\left | S_p(x) -S_q(x)\right |\le {b^2+q+1\over (q+1)^2}(\alpha-1)q$$and by tending $q\to\infty$ as Cauchy's criterion imposes we obtain$$\sup_{x\in [a,b]}\left | S_p(x) -S_q(x)\right |\le \alpha-1$$since this is true for every $\alpha>1$ therefore $$\sup_{x\in [a,b]}\left | S_p(x) -S_q(x)\right |\to 0$$and the proof is complete.

> **An alternative way**

Note that both$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(-1)^n\over n}=\ln 2\\\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(-1)^n\over n^2}$$are convergent, therefore $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{x^2+n}{n^2}$$ is uniformly convergent by investigating $\sum_{n=N}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{x^2+n}{n^2}$ for large enough $N$. Another way to say it is that $$|f_n(x)-f(x)|{=\left|\sum_{n=N}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{x^2+n}{n^2}\right|\\\le \sup_{x\in[a,b]}\left|\sum_{n=N}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{x^2+n}{n^2}\right|\\=\sup_{x\in[a,b]}\left|\sum_{n=N}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n}+x^2\sum_{n=N}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}\right|\\\le \left|\sum_{n=N}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\right|+\sup_{x\in[a,b]}x^2\left|\sum_{n=N}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}\right|\\=
\left|\sum_{n=N}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\right|+ \max\{a^2,b^2\}\cdot\left|\sum_{n=N}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}\right|}$$since both $\sum_{n=N}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ and $\sum_{n=N}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}$ tend to zero and $\max\{a^2,b^2\}$ is bounded, then $|f_n(x)-f(x)|$ can be bounded enough and hence the proof is complete.

Comment: For the OP approach to work we must have $\frac{b^2+q+1}{(q+1)^2}(p-q) \to 0$ as $q \to \infty$ for ANY $p > q$.  You constructed a specific $p(q)$. What if $p = q^{100}$ for any $q$?  Then  we have $$\frac{b^2+q+1}{(q+1)^2}(p-q) = (q^{99}-1)q\frac{b^2+q+1}{(q+1)^2} \to +\infty$$

Comment: Then we conclude that the supremum is less than $\infty$ which holds true automatically and carries to information

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the comment.  However if what you say above is true then you have proved that $\sum_{n \geqslant 1} \frac{x^2 + n}{n^2}$ has partial sums that form a Cauchy sequence and the (absolute) series is convergent. Do you believe it is?

Comment: Can't we use the second equivalent definition of the Cauchy criteria that is, $\left | S_{n+p}-S_p \right |=\left |\sum_{k=p+1}^{n+p} (-1)^k\frac{x^2+k}{k^2} \right |\leq \frac{b^2+p+1}{(p+1)^2} ×n$ ? (Only changed q )

Comment: It tends to zero as p goes to infinity for any n, right ?

Comment: @PedroAlvarès:  Uniform Cauchy criterion is that for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$  such that if $p > N$ then $|S_{q} -S_p| < \epsilon$ for ANY and ALL $q > p$. You are thinking fix $n$ and then the RHS goes to $0$.  I am saying that if there exists $\epsilon_0 > 0$ such that for any $p$ no matter how big I can find $n > 0$ such that $|S_{p+n} - S_p| > \epsilon_0$ then we can't prove the Cauchy criterion is satisfied. Again for any $p$ you pick I will pick $n = p^{100}$ and the RHS cannot be made smaller than any $\epsilon$ no matter how large $p$.

Comment: @PedroAlvares: Another problem with this answer in the second part is $|\sum_{n=N}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{x^2+n}{n^2}|  \leq \sup_{x\in[a,b]}\sum_{n=N}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{x^2+n}{n^2}$. How do we know the inequality is true here when the summands change sign. The LHS is positive since it is an absolute value, the RHS could be negative. This type of problem is precisely what the alternating series test and the more general Dirichlet test is supposed to handle.

Comment: @RRL: so I can use this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3168545/is-there-such-a-theorem-about-uniform-convergence?noredirect=1#comment6524189_3168545   ?

Comment: @PedroAlvarès: Yes you can work this out with the alternating series test by showing that $x_n = \frac{x^2+n}{n^2}$ is monotonically decreasing to $0$ as I said in my answer. Then $\left|\sum_{n= q+1}^p (-1)^n x_n\right| = x_{q+1} - [x_{q+2} - x_{q+3}] + \ldots < x_{q+1}$. Finally, bound the RHS for $x \in [a,b]$ to get uniform convergence.  The approach you started is not a tight enough bound because you have to multiply by $q-p$ and this as I said can be very large.

Comment: @RRL, you are right. I missed to write that point in my answer, so an absolute value was forgotten at the final answer. Now I fixed it. By my comment, I mean if you conclude that $0\le \sup(\cdot)<\infty$ and $0\le \sup(\cdot)<a$ for some $a>0$, then which one gives you more information? Of course you can choose $p=q^{99}$, but in that case, all the information you get is $\text{sup of something}<\infty$ which is most trivial.