# Is there such a theorem about uniform convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

If we have $\sum (-1)^nx_n$ and if $x_n>0$, and $\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty }x_n=0$ and $x_n$ is a decreasing sequence then

$\left | \sum_{n=q+1}^{p} (-1)^nx_n\right |\leq x_{q+1}$

And if $\underset{x}{sup}(x_{q+1})\rightarrow0 $ then the series converges uniformly

Comment: the first statement is true. The second makes no sense, what do you mean by supremum over all $x$'s?

Comment: To prove uniform convergence, I took supremum of both sides, if the R.H.S tends to zero ,then we're finshed.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, it should be $x_{q+1}$ that tends to zero ?

Comment: It is  given that $x_n$ goes to zero.

Comment: Oh okay, but the thing I didn't understad is why $\left | \sum_{n=q+1}^{p} (-1)^nx_n\right |\leq x_{q+1}$

Comment: I know that a sum is less than or equal (number of terms)times(biggest term)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably $x_n$ is a function of $x$ in some domain $D$ as you are concerned with uniform convergence.

Since $x_n$ is a decreasing sequence, $x_{n} - x_{n+1} > 0$ and

$$\left | \sum_{n=q+1}^{p} (-1)^nx_n\right| = \left |(-1)^{q+1}(x_{q+1} - x_{q+2} + x_{q+3} - x_{q+4} + \ldots) \right| \\= x_{q+1} - (\, x_{q+2} - x_{q+3}\, ) - (\, x_{q+3} - x_{q+4}\, ) - \ldots  \leqslant x_{q+1} \leqslant \sup_{x \in D} x_{q+1}
$$

Thus, if the RHS tends to $0$ as $q \to \infty$ then uniform convergence follows as the uniform Cauchy criterion is satisfied.